# How to pass ColdFusion cfoutput query row#/ID to another CFM or Function?

Tags: variables, coldfusion

I have a Coldfusion project I'm working on and I am displaying a list of announcements that have the details truncated with this type of layout:

**AnnouncmentList.cfc**

```
<cfoutput query="qAnnouncements">
    <tr>
        <Td style="white-space:normal;">
            #dateformat(qAnnouncements.Announcement_Send, 'ddd - mm/dd/yyyy')# <BR />
            <h4>#qAnnouncements.Announcement_Title#</h4><BR />
            #listFirst(wrap(qAnnouncements.Announcement_Content, 100), chr(10))#&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('abc123')">...more</a><BR /><BR />
        </Td>
   </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

When I click the "...more" link, I would like a popup to display and show just the content of the announcement that is clicked. I am able to display the correct announcement on the popup by simply adjusting my qAnnouncements query display with a WHERE clause to check the Announcement_ID, but I have to hard code this in at the moment.

So how can I properly pass the qAnnouncements.Announcement_ID of the link that is clicked from the list to my **AnnouncementPopup.cfc** file to then use for the adjusted query?

Summary: Want to pass Announcement_ID from the  in **AnnouncementList.cfc** -> **AnnouncementPopup.cfc**

Comment: It would help to see the code used to generate the popup, that calls AnnouncementPopup.cfc.

Comment: It might be as simple as making the popup call a .cfm with the id as a url variable.  That .cfm page could then invoke the function in your cfc.  If it's not that simple, what am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like getting the id into a url variable is the issue, but ... just a guess without the code. @johntc121 - Also, if you have a choice about what to use, the CF UI components aren't really recommended anymore as they use old js libs and are often buggy. Consider using an external js lib for the popups instead